# Continuity of function given product with continuous function is finite

Tags: real-analysis

This seems like a really simple question but I can not find a solution by myself:

Given the functions $f(x,y)$, $g(x,y)$ and $h(y)$, where, $g(x,y)$ is continuous in the $x$ coordinate and $h(y)$ is finite in its domain, if the functions verify the following relation
$$
f(x,y)g(x,y)=h(y)~,
$$
can anything be said about the continuity of $f(x,y)$ in the coordinate $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $f(x,y)=\frac{h(y)}{g(x,y)}$ which is a composition of continuous fucntions, as long as $g(x,y)\neq 0$. When $g(x,y)=0, h(y)=0$ the value of $f(x,y)$ can be anything. So we have $f(x,y)$ is continuous in $x$ if $g(x,y)\neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and accurate answer.